# Events and Observers in Magento

Tags: event-observer, ce-1.8.1.0

In app/code/core/Mage/Customer/conrtrollers/AccountController.php there is

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
            array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
        );
```

How this event code i.e customer_register_success is fired in magento when dispatchEvent is called.

Comment: question is not clear....breify in details

Comment: read more http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the function `dispatchEvent` in the class `Mage_Core_Model_App` you will see that the code works as follows:

*NOTE: for this example I will use the event `controller_front_init_routers` simply because this happens a lot and is easier to step through the code with*

Firstly what happens is that all the observers set-up in the config are loaded into an array of the format:

```
$observers['observer_name'] = array(
    'type'  => 'observer_type,
    'model' => 'observer_model',
    'method'=> 'method_to_call',
    'args'  => 'arguments_array',
);
```

This matches the way you define an observer via xml as follows.

```
<events>
    <event_name>
        <observers>
            <observer_name>
                <type>observer_type</type>
                <class>observer_model</class>
                <method>method_to_call</method>
            </observer_name>
        </observers>
    </event_name>
</events>
```

For our example the array looks as follows.

```
array(1) {
  ["cms"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["model"]=>
    string(26) "Mage_Cms_Controller_Router"
    ["method"]=>
    string(21) "initControllerRouters"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Then what happens is the dispatchEvent function checks to see if the event we want to dispatch has something listening to it. If it does not then it wont continue any further but when it does it continues to build an event object and observer object.

It then loops through all the stored event information, sets the data arguments and calls the desired method on the desired object. Note that by default the model is loaded as a singleton.

```
foreach ($events[$eventName]['observers'] as $obsName=>$obs) {
    $observer->setData(array('event'=>$event));
    Varien_Profiler::start('OBSERVER: '.$obsName);
    switch ($obs['type']) {
        case 'disabled':
            break;
        case 'object':
        case 'model':
            $method = $obs['method'];
            $observer->addData($args);
            $object = Mage::getModel($obs['model']);
            $this->_callObserverMethod($object, $method, $observer);
            break;
        default:
            $method = $obs['method'];
            $observer->addData($args);
            $object = Mage::getSingleton($obs['model']);
            $this->_callObserverMethod($object, $method, $observer);
            break;
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('OBSERVER: '.$obsName);
}
```

One final thing that happens is that the `_callObserverMethod` function checks to see if the desired method exists and when it does not it throws an exception.

So for our example we will be using the model `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router` and the method `initControllerRouters`.